The deviation of the sample correlation matrix from its true value
In the High Dimensional Probability (HDP) book by Roman Vershynin, I found the concentration inequality of the covariance matrix
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|\Sigma_n-\Sigma\|_2\le C_K\sqrt{\frac{p}{n}}\right)\ge1-2\exp\left(-p\right)
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm.
Now, I am interested in the concentration inequality of the correlation coefficient matrix: bound $\|\Gamma_n-\Gamma\|_2$ in a high probability,  where $\Gamma=D^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Sigma D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $D=diag\left(\Sigma\right)$. So What is the best result available? Can the results of the correlation matrix be obtained directly from the results of the covariance matrix?
UPDATE
My attempt:
A useful theorem is provided in Kenneth R. Davidson, Stanislaw J, Szarek - Local Operator Theory, Random Matrices and Banach Spaces, page 42 (THM II.13).

Given $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $m\le n$, put $\beta=m/n$ and consider the $n\times m$ random matrix $\Gamma$ whose entries are real, independent Gaussian random variables following the $\mathcal{N}\left(0,1/n\right)$ law. Let the singular values be $s_1\left(\Gamma\right)\ge\cdots\ge s_1\left(\Gamma\right)$. Then for any $t >0$,
$$
\max\left\{\mathcal{P}\left(s_1\left(\Gamma\right)\ge 1+\sqrt{\beta}+t\right),\mathcal{P}\left(s_m\left(\Gamma\right)\le 1-\sqrt{\beta}-t\right)\right\}\le \exp\left(-nt^2/2\right)
$$

I wonder that
could ${\Gamma}_n$ be decomposed as ${\Gamma}_n=XX^{\top}$ where $X$ denotes a $p\times n$ matrix with Gaussian entries that have zero mean and variance $\frac{1}{n}$. If this decomposition is correct, the theorem mentioned above could be used directly.

Duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/656344/6633 posted on stats.SE

@DilipSarwate I didn't get an answer there so I'm asking here. Please let me know if there are any community rules that I need to abide by.
